# How can I get all the records between the start date and end date in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, date

In my blade file there is a search bar on leave duration column, leave duration column contail startDate & endDate,

In my database i have 2 fields start date and end date, and if i search a date who lies between startDate & endDate than it will give me output,

here in my controller file

```
public function listOfLeave(Request $request)
{
    $from      = date('1001-01-01');
    $to        = date('9999-12-31');
    $allLeaves = null;
    if (
        !empty($request->input('name')) ||
        !empty($request->input('leaveType')) ||
        !empty($request->input('leaveDate')) ||
        !empty($request->input('appliedDate')) ||
        !empty($request->input('status'))
    ) {
        $flg = false;
        if (!empty($request->input('name'))) {
            $flg       = true;
            $allLeaves = LeaveManagement::where('username', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('name')}%");
        }
        if (!empty($request->input('leaveType'))) {
            if ($flg) {
                $allLeaves = $allLeaves->orWhere('typeOfLeave', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('leaveType')}%");
            } else {
                $allLeaves = LeaveManagement::where('typeOfLeave', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('leaveType')}%");
            }
        }
        if (!empty($request->input('leaveDate'))) {
            if ($flg) {
                $allLeaves = $allLeaves->orWhereBetween('startDate', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('leaveDate')}%");
            } else {
                $allLeaves = LeaveManagement::where('startDate', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('leaveDate')}%");
            }
        }
        if (!empty($request->input('appliedDate'))) {
            if ($flg) {
                $allLeaves = $allLeaves->orWhere('startDate', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('appliedDate')}%");
            } else {
                $allLeaves = LeaveManagement::where('startDate', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('appliedDate')}%");
            }
        }
        if (!empty($request->input('status'))) {
            if ($flg) {
                $allLeaves = $allLeaves->orWhere('status', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('status')}%");
            } else {
                $allLeaves = LeaveManagement::where('status', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('status')}%");
            }
        }
        $allLeaves = $allLeaves->orderBy('username', 'ASC')
            ->orderBy('typeOfLeave', 'ASC')
            ->orderBy('startDate', 'ASC')
            ->orderBy('startDate', 'ASC')
            ->orderBy('status', 'ASC')
            ->paginate(2);
        return view('pages.newleaverequest')->with(['allLeaves' => $allLeaves]);
    } else {
        $allLeaves = LeaveManagement::orderBy('username', 'ASC')->paginate(5);
    }
    $allLeaves->appends(['name' => Input::get('name')]);
    return view('pages.newleaverequest', compact('allLeaves'));
}
```

How can i get records who lies between startdate and enddate???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I think this should help you:

```
if (!empty($request->input('leaveDate'))) {
    if ($flg) {
        $allLeaves = $allLeaves->whereDate('endDate', '<', $request->input('leaveDate'));
    } else {
        $allLeaves = LeaveManagement::whereDate('endDate', '<', $request->input('leaveDate'));
    }
}

if (!empty($request->input('appliedDate'))) {
    if ($flg) {
        $allLeaves = $allLeaves->whereDate('startDate', '>', $request->input('appliedDate'));
    } else {
        $allLeaves = LeaveManagement::whereDate('startDate', '>', $request->input('appliedDate'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ..->whereBetween('your_column_name_date', [$from ,$to]);

Comment: OP says that he has two fields `start date` and `end date`. He wants to fetch the records which are in between these two dates

Answer (score 0):

In your query you will need a where clause for that to filter those results. To get data inside a specific range you can use the `whereBetween` clause.

The syntax will be like:

```
    $allLeaves = $allLeaves->where('startDate', '>', $from)
                            ->where('endDate', '<', $to)
                            ->orderBy('username', 'ASC')
                            ->orderBy('typeOfLeave', 'ASC')
                            ->orderBy('startDate', 'ASC')
                            ->orderBy('startDate', 'ASC')
                            ->orderBy('status', 'ASC')
                            ->paginate(2);
```

Comment: OP says that he has two fields `start date` and `end date`. He wants to fetch the records which are in between these two dates

Comment: Nope that won't work, what is $from and $to?

Comment: These are your variables that you have in your code at the top.

Comment: @Zain edited my code, you were right OP needs to compare 2 columns.

Comment: Nope not workng,

Comment: the columns startDate and endData which data format are they using? I assumed they are using the data format you use in your `$from` `$to` variables since you hardcode them. Are you sure they are like this or are they timestamps? Because above query will get 2 records per page based on the order you set which have startData higher than the date of your `$from` variable and endDate lower than your `$to` variable.

Comment: No this is the format in my collection date format is Y-m-d, Should I write dates in $from and $to manually?

Comment: But you have. based on the code you posted above these are your variables:

    `$from      = date('1001-01-01');`
    `$to        = date('9999-12-31');`

Comment: yeah it is, still it not give me rocords which lies between startdate and enddate

Answer (score 0):

Here is getting records from users table and get all data of given $start and $end date between records. So you can see following simple example and understand how it is works.

```
$start = '2019-04-01';
$end = '2019-04-18';
$users = User::select("users.*")

                ->whereBetween('created', [$start, $end])

                ->get();


dd($users);
```